# Maximize $\gamma$ such that $A+\lambda B-\gamma C\succeq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, positive-definite, semidefinite-programming

This question follows this previous one: [Maximize $\gamma$ such that $A+\gamma B\succeq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851946/maximize-gamma-such-that-a-gamma-b-succeq-0)

This time, $A\succ 0$, $B$ is indefinite and $C = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & \dots & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

The goal is to optimize the following problem:
$$
\max_{\lambda,\gamma} \gamma:A+\lambda B-\gamma C\succeq 
0$$

For the previous question, an answer was provided:
$$\gamma=-\frac{1}{\lambda_{\min}(A^{-1}B)}$$
where $\lambda_{\min}(A)$ refers to the minimum eigenvalue of $A$.

I don't know if it is possible to obtain such a result for the current problem. Surely, it is optimizable using a SDP solver, but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: Can $\lambda$ be negative?

Comment: You've only specified the first and the last elements on the diagonal of $C$. What are the other diagonal entries?

Comment: All the other entries of $C$ are zero. $\lambda$ should be positive.